# Illustrated Tzara'at

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, color, pictures, tzaraas-negaim

I have indirectly heard of someone in a school (I think it's a yeshiva student) who is doing a research project on various medical conditions. She decided to discuss *tzara'at* and compare what the Torah describes and compare it with current research of similar medical and environmental conditions. (E.g. there is *tzara'at* that appears on the skin - (medical / biological) vs. the form that appears on vessels and houses (environmental)).

The Torah mentions various colors and shades in describing most of *tzara'at*. To better understand what this looked like, she was wondering if anyone has published illustrations on these various conditions. It could be either in book form or on-line. If you know of such sources, please post them.

While the student is focusing mainly on the skin forms (there are several mentioned), if there is a book that illustrates and discusses the vessel, clothing, and house forms, that would be a huge bonus.

Comment: not what you are looking for, but cool to see: http://cafe.themarker.com/post/3426591/

Answer (score 1):

Edit: [This link](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=16150#p359581) shows exactly what you are looking for.

---

My original post:

I can imagine that it would be quite difficult to show different shades of white printed in a book, being that the page and ink colors are easily changed over time, as well as being hard to produce in first place.  The same might apply to screen lighting.  It also does not seem like there would be such a large market for it, so I would assume that it does not exist.  Even if it does exist, I can only assume that there would be some controversy over the actual colorings portrayed, just like [this recent case](http://jewishweek.timesofisrael.com/debate-roils-over-orthodox-menstruation-app/).

That being said, I have never seen the inside of this Sefer myself, but according to the description of [Sefer Mar'os Chaim](https://books.google.ca/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D.html?id=2ejRrQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y), it is an illustrated Mishnayos Negaim.  I don't know if it actually contains "colors and shades" that you would be looking for, but it might.

Comment: +1 Benefit of vagueness granted. The description of the book, seems like this may do the job. If there is some way to get a pic of a page form the book, that would help me decide, better. A *niddah* app?? For real?? I need to read this article. I guess there's no shortage to accommodating laziness :-(

Comment: @DanF I'm surprised you haven't heard the controversy earlier.

Comment: Age. *Niddah* is no longer a concern for us!

Comment: @DanF I didn't hear about it because I was hoping to use it, I heard about it because it was all over the frum news/hack!  There was even a headlines show about it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see these seforim (both from the same author):

- [The Laws Of Tzoraas: (The Pictorial Avodah Series)](https://mekorjudaica.com/the-laws-of-tzoraas.html?___SID=U) by Menachem
  Moshe Oppen. 85 pages. (online [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/47038)).
- [The Laws of Taharah: (The Pictorial Avodah Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1560622695) by Menachem Moshe Oppen. 170 pages.(online [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/47037))

Both have many illustrations (unfortunately not entirely in color) presenting a pictorial guide to the portions of the Torah dealing with Tzoraas and taharah. Although they're not exhaustive and too much detailed, they help in many aspects picturing this issues, and seems to be very close to what your are looking for.

Comment: The OP stated: "The Torah mentions various colors and shades in describing most of tzara'at. To better understand what this looked like, she was wondering if anyone has published illustrations on these various conditions."   To me that sounds like something without color or shading is not useful to them.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Techncially, based on my question, you are correct. But having another option is still useful. Also, of course, a scanned online copy via Hebrewbooks.org would probably not be in color even if the original is. All I'm suggesting is that if you down-voted, that's one thing. But, the other resources are still useful to get another / supplemental interpretation.

Comment: To be fair, the first book do contain some color. A quick google search comproves that: http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/prodview.asp?idProduct=35564

Comment: Ok, fair, I'll reverse it